# Duplicate symbol error when using TouchDB and FMDB wrapper together

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb, touchdb

In my app I'm storing data using `TouchDB`. I've added `TouchDB.framework`, everything worked fine. Then I had to work with a sqlite database in the same application, and as I'm accustomed  with `FMDB` wrapper, I added it to the project. On build I received the following error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FMDatabase in:
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../armv7/FMDatabase.o
    /Users/me/.../TouchDB.framework/TouchDB(FMDatabase.o)
```

I guess that `TouchDB` framework contains `FMDatabase` file as well, but it's missing from Headers folder. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't link against FMDatabase, just link against TouchDB.  Since I'm not sure how you're setting up those links, that's as precise as I can be.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer, you mean not include FMDB files (like FMDatabase) in the project? If so how to use them?

Comment: @Euroboy If TouchDB doesn't include the FMDB .h files, you can add those to your project, but don't add the FMDB .m files.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're including the FMDB .m files, so just select all of them in the project window, open the inspector panel on the right, and make sure none of the targets are checked under Target Membership.